# Python regex to capture only first occurrence of a numeric match

Tags: python, regex

I used a simple python regex like `value="(.+?)"` to capture values in my xml data only to realize the output had strings & number ranges, which messed up the data processing downstream. I need to capture only numeric values. When there is a range like say *"19-20"* I want to capture only 19.

Sample Data:

```
value="19-20"
value="19.984"
value="slow"
value="19.99kg/m2"
value="107"
value="221lb"
```

This is as close as I could get

My partially working regex1:

```
value="([0-9]{1,3})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,2})"
```

My partially working regex2:

```
value="(.+?)(?:kg/m2|lb)?"
```

This is what I am struggling to get in the output

```
Match1: 19
Match2: 19.984
Match3: Null (or empty)
Match4: 19.99
Match5: 107
Match6: 221
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per OP 6 matches expected, Match3 = Null
use this pattern

```
^value="((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/341)

Comment: Thanks Alpha. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\bvalue="(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

and grab value from captured group #1

`(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` matches 1 or more digits followed by optional part i.e. decimal  and digits after decimal.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uQ6bL1/2)

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/fyc4xT)

Comment: On the sample data it seems to work well, let me integrate it with my code & run it real quick. I am positive this will clean up a big part of my output.

Comment: Yes it did work out. I used Alpha Bravo's version, as I could update my pandas data frame with an empty string for [row, column] value where nothing matched. Thanks for channelizing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
import re

tests = ['value="19-20"',
'value="19.984"',
'value="slow"',
'value="19.99kg/m2"',
'value="107"',
'value="221lb"']


for txt in tests:
    print re.findall(r'value="([\d][\d\.]*)', txt)
```

Comment: Your code does capture 20 as well in 19-20. Now regex(ically) speaking nothing wrong, but in my downstream processing it will freak out to find two values 19 & 20 for same [index, column] combination.

Comment: you mean without the value= part of the regex.  I was assuming that was part of the input string and therefore only taking the first number (w/ decimal) after that.

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/6akIPD). The regex is incorrect a bit, I'd use `r'value="(\d[\d.]*)'`. But this answer is just not the best.

Comment: @GarrettR - I see what you are saying. It captures only the first part. Let me run it on my file & also read about the capturing / non-capturing groups in detail over the weekend.